# two calculated columns that need each other

Tags: sql, teradata

Disclaimer: I'm using Teradata and trying to build a view

I have this view I'm querying from:

```
    +----------+------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+
    | scenario | week | sold_store | sold_customer | returns | price |
    +----------+------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+
    | past     |    1 |       5000 |          2500 | 100     |    50 |
    | future   |    2 |        100 |            50 | null    |    50 |
    | future   |    3 |         50 |            10 | null    |    50 |
    +----------+------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+
```

I need to calculate the future returns, as well as an "opening_stock", which is how many items we still have available for sale in stores.

When scenario is 'past', returns = returns (because we already have data for the past)

Returns, when scenario is future = -0.05 * Opening_stock (let's call it returns_v2)

Opening_stock = running total = SUM(sold_store - sold_customer + returns) over (ORDER by week) (Except that the 3 values should be the one of the week-1)

The thing is, for returns, saying

```
Case Scenario
WHEN 'past' then returns
ELSE -0.05 * Opening_SIT
END as returns_v2
```

doesn't work because Opening_SIT used the original "returns" column (through a LAG() that I kept as a column in a subquery, for instance) instead of the one I just calculated with my CASE statement.

My end goal would be to get:

```
+----------+------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+---------------+
| scenario | week | sold_store | sold_customer | returns | price | Opening_stock |
+----------+------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+---------------+
| past     |    1 |       5000 |          2500 | -100    |    50 | null          |
| future   |    2 |        200 |            50 | -120    |    50 | 2400          |
| future   |    3 |         50 |            10 | -121.5  |    50 | 2430          |
+----------+------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+---------------+
```

The main issue is that Opening_Stock uses returns of week-1, which it should do for the first future week, but then I need it to take returns_v2 of week-1.
But also, returns_v2 needs to be able to use Opening_Stock.

I don't know how to write my query to be able to do that, no matter how many subqueries I use... It feels like an infinite loop that I can't get out of.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to get, but this simple *Cumultive Sum* seems to return the expected *opening stock*:

```
Sum(sold_store - sold_customer + returns)
Over (ORDER BY Week
      ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND 1 Preceding)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I've worked this through now. First off, you are showing your returns as a negative #.  If you had 100 returns, don't you want to **add** that to your running stock?

Here's my logic, based on adding returns. Basically, you have to calculate your running total twice. You calculate it in the inner query, and then use that value in the outer query. If you use negative numbers for the returns, it matches your numbers.

```
create volatile table vt_foo
(scenario varchar(20),
wk int,
sold_store int,
sold_customer int,
rtrns int,
price int)
on commit preserve rows;


insert into vt_foo values (' past     ',1,5000,2500,100,50);
insert into vt_foo values (' future   ',2,100,50, null    ,50);
insert into vt_foo values (' future   ',3,50,10, null    ,50);

select
t.*,
sum(opening_stock) over (order by wk asc rows unbounded preceding) as running_stock
from (
select
t.*,
Sum(sold_store - sold_customer + coalesce(ret2,0)) Over (ORDER BY wk ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND 1 Preceding) as final_running_stock
from (
select
t.*,
Sum(sold_store - sold_customer + coalesce(rtrns,0)) Over (ORDER BY wk ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND 1 Preceding) as running_stock,
case
  when trim(scenario) = 'past' then cast ( rtrns as decimal(10,2))
  when trim(scenario) = 'future' then  0.05 * running_stock
 end as ret2

from
vt_foo t
```

That returns

```
    | scenario  | wk | sold_store | sold_customer | rtrns | price | running_stock | ret2  | final_running_stock |
    +-----------+----+------------+---------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------------------+
    | past      |  1 |       5000 |          2500 | 100   |    50 | ?             | 100   | ?                   |
    | future    |  2 |        100 |            50 | ?     |    50 | 2600          | 130   | 2600                |
    | future    |  3 |         50 |            10 | ?     |    50 | 2650          | 132.5 | 2780                |
    +-----------+----+------------+---------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------------------+
```